# Symfony: call command in controller for lengthy action

Tags: symfony, command-line

I have a application in which I can generate raw export in xls.

The problem is that the xls generation can be very long, more than the timeout duration.

I've checked and my query isn't the culprit (takes <2s for a regular query), but the xls generation is very long (for several thousand lines, I put different colors in cells, conditionally display data...).

I was thinking about the command, which runs in CLI, without timeout problem.

I can't use it directly, because the data to be generated has to be called by users (without cli access).

So I thought about [calling the command in my controller](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/command_in_controller.html)
The user would choose the parameters in a form, send the form, and then in the controller, the parameters would be passed to the command that would do the heavy lifting.

My question is: In this case, is the command called in the CLI context (with CLI timeout = 0) or is it called in the application (Web) context (with timeout <50s) ? In the latter case, this would be useless, and I would be grateful for any advice on any alternate method to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook case for a message queue.

RabbitMq is recommended, and easy to use with Symfony.

You will have a producer, which will generate a message and put it in a queue. This will be done in your controller.

The db query and the sheet generation should be placed in the consumer (the command running in the background, picking messages from the queue and processing them).

When the sheet is ready, save it as a file, and perhaps log it in the database with a unique ID.

This migth sound difficult, but it is very simple, and you should learn it anyway :)

A problem is showing the result to the user. The simplest way is to refresh the browser every X seconds. Other choices include polling with ajax, and websocket based notifications from the server.

Comment: To complement your response, he can use MercureBundle, as alternative to websocket, to dispatch a notification to the client with the url of the new xls document.